# Which APIs are cheaper than (SpyFu, SimilarWeb) for finding your competitors online?

Tags: web-development, api, web-apis

I have a small business and I'm looking for an API to find my competitors online.

I don't need 10,000 rows of data, probably just my website url's top 5 competitors.

Answer (score 1):

The most effective way to go about this is to use [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com) and [Google Ad Words](https://adwords.google.com/home/) to find out the key words which usually bring up your site on organic search and then hit the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview?csw=1) with those keywords. This quick search can yield as many competitors' URLs as you desire. You can even cross check with [Alexa Web Rankings](http://www.alexa.com/) to see how well your competitors are performing.